# How to define simple rule in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to define the following rule in prolog:

when `X` is thirsty, `X` should go to the bar.

after, I would ask prolog `thirsty(X)` and prolog should give back go(bar)

I have tried it on the following way:

```
go(Y).
thirsty(X) :- go(bar).
```

But when I test it with

```
thirsty(bob).
```

The result will only be `true`. Can someone help me what I have to change to get `go(bar)` as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when `X` is thirsty, `X` should go to the bar.

Looking at the first part of this sentence, "when `X` is thirsty”, there’s clearly a property thirsty that `X` can have, so `thirsty` sounds like a good predicate (`thirsty(X)` means `X` is thirsty).

Then there’s a few ways to look at the second part of the sentence, "`X` should go to the bar”, I’ll write some below in order of increasing complexity with the last being what I think you want:

1. One is that “should go to the bar” is a property of `X`, in which case you can define the predicate `should_go_to_the_bar` as a predicate so that `should_go_to_the_bar(X)` means `X` should go to the bar.

Then your program can be:

```
thirsty(bob).
should_go_to_the_bar(X) :- thirsty(X).

?- should_go_to_the_bar(bob).
True
```

2. Another is that “should go to” may be a relation between `X` and `the_bar`, so that `should_go_to(X, the_bar)` means that X should go to the_bar.

Then your program can be:

```
thirsty(bob).
should_go_to_the_bar(X, the_bar) :- thirsty(X).

?- should_go_to(bob, X).
X = the_bar
```

3. Another is that "should" may be a property of actions like `go_to(X, the_bar)`, so that `should(go_to(the_bar))` means that it should be that go_to(X, the_bar).

Then your program can be:

```
thirsty(bob).
should(go_to(X, the_bar)) :- thirsty(X).

?- should(X).
X = should(go_to(bob, the_bar))
```

4. Last I’ll go into is that "should" may be a relation between a person `X` and an action they can do like `go_to(X, the_bar)`, so that `should(X, go_to(X, the_bar)` means that X should go_to(X, the_bar) i.e. X should make it true that “X goes to the bar".

Then your program can be:

```
thirsty(bob).
should(X, go_to(X, the_bar)) :- thirsty(X).

?- should(bob, Action).
Action = go_to(bob, the_bar)
```

I think this last interpretation is closest to what you want.

Comment: when I try your last program, I always get a errormessage: ` Undefined procedure: thirsty/1` Can you help me, to resolve this?

Comment: @Bennodual Yes sorry I made a mistake, since `thirsty(bob)` is a fact you are supposing to be true, it should be in the program (and not the query as I had written earlier). Now it works as intended. It's declared in the program that bob is thirsty and the declared relationship to what he should do, and the query then asks what should bob do.

Comment: - Thank you for your last response. It works now on this way. One more little question: can I load the program (without the fact `thirsty(bob)` with consult() and add after the fact `thirsty(bob)` (and remove it after)?

Comment: Sorry - I askd to fast. I have found it: `assert()` and `retract()` do the trick.

Comment: @BennoDual Great! :)

Answer (score 3):

`go(Y).` as a rule doesn't really mean anything, other than *go anywhere* perhaps. When you assert rules in Prolog, you should be able to assign some semantic meaning to them. Your rule says, *If `X` is thirsty, then the `bar` is a place to go* which of course always succeeds since `bar` is always a place to go, as is any place else you might want to go according to your rule, `go(Y)`. Since you didn't use `X` anywhere in your `thirsty(X)` predicate clause body, it's never used (so you probably saw a singleton variable warning about that).

Defining a good rule in Prolog is first about stating your rule in a sensible way first. Perhaps a reasonable rule involving a person might be:

> `Person` goes to the bar *if* `Person` is thirsty.

This might be stated as:

```
go_bar(Person) :- thirsty(Person).
```

Or more generally,

```
goes(Person, bar) :- thirsty(Person).
goes(Person, restaurant) :- hungry(Person).
```

Then you'd need to assert some facts about the person (or query the user for these facts):

```
thirsty(bob).
```

With that fact asserted, the following query can result:

```
?- goes(bob, X).
X = bar
```