# Rule in Prolog with Variable

Tags: prolog

Like the answer in [How to define simple rule in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611110/how-to-define-simple-rule-in-prolog) i define the following programm:

```
should(X, go_to(X, toilet)) :- full_bladder(X).

?- assert(full_bladder(bob)).
true.
?- should(bob, Action).
Action = go_to(bob, toilet)
```

I add now the facts:

```
?- assert(lastlocation(bob, floor)).
true.
?- assert(currentlocation(bob, toilet)).
true.
?- assert(empty_bladder(bob)).
true.
```

How can I now define the rule for:

"when currentlocation is toilet and empty_bladder then go to lastlocation"

This rule should ensure that for the following question

```
?- should(bob, Action).
```

the result should be

```
Action = go_to(bob, floor).
```

I hope, someone can help me, how to define the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the rule:

```
should(X, go_to(X, floor)) :- empty_bladder(X),currentlocation(X, toilet).
```

The above says: if clause empty_bladder(X) exists and also currentlocation(X, toilet) then return as second parameter go_to(X, floor).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But instead of use of the static value floor, I want to use the value of lastlocation for X. Is this possible?

Comment: @BennoDual, this is not possible since the lastlocation has to do with time, in Prolog (and first order logic) we can describe states (input - output) not time...